# jqPlot - Styling Custom Features (i.e. ticks: CustomTicks)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot, data-visualization

I have a couple for jqPlot Bar charts and I'm setting the ticks with a different array from the data that's being plotted as illustrated below. I've noticed that when using some extra features like this it becomes more difficult or at least different from the Doc to style these element of the Charts. For instance, I need to customize the tool tip so to get it to render I had to implement an undocumented property called `tooltipContentEditor`.Further, it has become an impossible task to style these elements. In this case, my tick labels are 5pt font and I need to increase the size. So I'm looking for the proper method of styling these components once they have been 'customized'.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;
var s1 = Data;//[[10,1],[15,2],[13,3]] Plot Data is [seriesArry][0] & series is [Series][1]
var Ticks = [[0,'a'],[1,'b'],[2,'c']];//Custom ticks.

plot1 = $.jqplot('Chart1', [s1], {
    // Only animate if we're not using excanvas (not in IE 7 or IE 8)..
    animate: !$.jqplot.use_excanvas,
    title: 'Chart1',
    seriesDefaults: {
        renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
        pointLabels: { show: true, location: 'e', edgeTolerance: -15 },//Point labels aren't rendering. Not sure why
        rendererOptions: {
            barDirection: 'horizontal',
            barWidth: 15,
            color: 'rgb(230,230,245)',
        },
    },

    axesDefaults: {},

    axes: {
        xaxis: {
            renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
            pointLabels: { show: true },
        },

        yaxis: {
            ticks: Ticks,//Custom ticks. [[0,'a'],[1,'b'],[2,'c']] 
            tickOptions: { fontSize: '15pt'; },
        }//end yaxis
    },

    highlighter: { 
        show: true,
        tooltipContentEditor: tooltipContentEditor,//Function to customize content of tooltip
        sizeAdjust: 15,
    },

    grid: {
        background: 'rgb(72, 102, 137)',
    },

});
});//End Document.Ready
```

Answer (score 0):

This is issue was I was missing a reference to `jqplot.canvasTextRenderer.js`. Causing exception to been thrown:

```
this._textRenderer = new $.jqplot.CanvasFontRenderer(ropts); 
                     Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

**Answer:**

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="JS/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.canvasTextRenderer.js"></script>
```